# How are reserved and formal synonyms?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

In the dictionary reserved means - not revealing emotions and formal means - prim or stiff. I saw they were synonym in the Google dictionary. What makes these two words similar, I wonder?

Comment: In *formal* settings, the etiquette was one of not showing your emotions, i.e. of being reserved. [*Formal*](https://www.google.com/#q=define%20formal) = "done in accordance with rules of convention or etiquette" and that etiquette used to require suppression of emotions.

Comment: What is 'the dictionary'? Are they all the same?

Comment: There are very few synonyms where the two terms are equivalent in all senses.

Comment: The two expressions are only synonyms in some senses. There are plenty of people who wear informal clothes and speak in an informal manner but reveal very little about themselves. In contrast the Oscar ceremonies are very formal in both organisation and dress but there's often a bit of emotion on show.

Answer (score 2):

[*Reserved*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/reserved) means "tending to keep your feelings or thoughts private rather than showing them," while [*formal*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/formal_1) can mean "correct or conservative in style, and appropriate for official or serious situations or occasions." The words are related in that someone who is formal by nature or upbringing will also likely tend to be reserved. They are not ["true synonyms,"](http://blog.dictionary.com/true-synonym/) however, in that they are not interchangeable but are related in terms of [*manners*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/good_manners) and [*comportment*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/comportment). See the linked definition of [*synonym*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synonym) at merriam-webster.com.

Comment: What are 'true synonyms'? The only useful definition for _synonym[s]_ I've seen given on ELU (and it's not, to my knowledge, been challenged) is 'two or more words having the same or very nearly the same meaning in at least some of their senses'.

Comment: Just FYI: Google Dictionary borrows definitions from [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/) most of the time.

Comment: @Edwin, I agree. I've now put the term "true synonyms" in quotes (with a link to a dictionary.com blog post that argues there is no such thing), but I can't speak for the creators of the Google dictionary. Should I remove the word "true" from my answer? Wouldn't it be presumptuous of me to claim the Google dictionary is wrong?

Comment: if we consider this definition of 'informal' -having a relaxed, friendly, or unofficial style, manner, or nature-  it sort of casts a bit more flavor on what formal "is not"

Comment: The [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synonym) definition (which I'm glad to find) is the one not to argue with. The term 'synonym' becomes useless if all the conditions your linked article (which is very good apart from terminology) mentions are demanded. // 'Not always interchangeable' expresses the idea.